# Central limit theorem on a linear combination

Tags: convergence, central-limit-theorem

I am looking for the name and the formulation of a CLT variant that states that a linear combination of random variables with the same mean and standard deviation will converge under a specific condition (Lyapunov CLT condition if I remember well), as long as the linear combination does not depend too much on a single random variable.

Comment: Upon rescaling the random variables according to the coefficients, the linear combination is just a sum, which places you right back into a classical CLT setting. However, the phrase "depend ... on a single random variable" raises questions about precisely what you are asking. Are the coefficients of the linear combination themselves random variables or not?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The coefficients of the linear combination themselves are not random variables. In my memory this stipulation was there to prevent the case where the sum would depend too much on the random variable with a prevalent coefficient and not be Gaussian anymore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Lindeberg condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition) does what you want. The linear combination is: $$\sum_{i=1}^na_i \xi_i$$

Define a new set of variables $x_i=a_i\xi_i$, they'll have the following means and variances: $\mu_{x_i}=a_i\mu_{\xi_i}$ and $\sigma^2_{x_i}=a_i^2\sigma^2_{\xi_i}$.

The Lindeberg condition says that as long as none of the $\sigma^2_{x_i}$ dominate the sum of variances $s^2_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma^2_{x_i}$, the variable $$S_n=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i - \mu_{x_i}\right)}{s_n}$$ tends to the standard normal distribution.